Excel Powerquery use the PDF connector UI for multiple PDF files AND choose the tables first
I am using the PDF connector UI to choose specific tables before they are converted by a function I've created.  The connector is great as it lets you choose the tables for a single file.  However when I do a folder of PDFs I don't have the ability to choose the tables for each file.  Is there a way to do this?
Below describes my current process and as a result it's currently limited to one PDF file per one excel file as I use #sections to pull out pdf tables I've chosen for a chosen PDF file.
Create a copy of the master excel file first, then goto PQ and delete any old PDF tables.  Then create a new PDF source, select the tables using the PDF connector.  A query is created for each table I've selected.  I then have an independent query which combines these queries together (in brief: #sections > filter to the queries I need (Tables0xxx) > call a function for each of the tables > expand > tidy up).  This is then loaded to a table in excel.
If I was able to use the PDF connector UI for multiple PDF files to choose the tables I would need to ensure the filenames can be used to separate the results (effectively a table for each file).
Is this (all) possible?
Showing an example of the query that is produced by the PDF connector

This is an excerpt of my CombinedTable query M Code.  It uses the #sections (hidden?) ability to get a list of the queries / tables so that I can then use this to call my function for each table that I've selected to process in the PDF connector UI.
let
Source = #sections,
Section1 = Source[Section1],
#"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Section1),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each Text.StartsWith([Name], "Table") and Text.Contains([Name], "Page")),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Name", "TableName"}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Renamed Columns",{{"TableName", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Invoked Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "ConvertPDF", each ConvertPDF([Value])),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function1",{"Value"}),
#"Expanded ConvertPDF" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "ConvertPDF", {"field1", "field2", "field3"}, {"field1", "field2", "field3"}),
in
#"Expanded ConvertPDF"

